# Map Fields screen with jQuery (ASP.NET WebForms)

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, dictionary, field

Need to understand the best way to map all the fields that I have on my screen (divs, imgs, inputs, dropdows, tables, etc ...). I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('body > *').mouseenter(function () {
        $('*').removeClass('objectFocus');
        $(this).addClass('objectFocus');
    });

    $('body > *').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('objectFocus');
    });

    $('*').on('click', '.objectFocus', function () {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
        $(this).removeClass('objectFocus');
    });

});
```

But I am facing problem with objects inside divs or tables. I know it is possible to use the feature `.children()` or `.parent()`. I would like to know the best way to do this, a generic form that I can access from a text box to div which is the same.

I have this in my jsFiddle: [**Not working as expected**](http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/Xuj5t/1/)

Him when we hover over the objects on the screen, is added a red border on them ... but when we insert objects inside a `div`, unfortunately it only enhances the parent `div`.

apparently it works: [**Expected Result (but not including divs)**](http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/Xuj5t/2/)

Anyone have any solution? Perhaps using `jQuery.map()` we get the result?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('body').on('mouseenter','input',function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('objectFocus');
  });
  $('body').on('click','.objectFocus',function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    $(this).removeClass('objectFocus');
  });
});
```

Comment: I need to highlight the object that the mouse is over.I can not do only for input.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* js */

 $('body').on('focus','input', function () {
    $(this).addClass('objectFocus');
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});

$('body').on('blur','input', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('objectFocus');
});

/* css */

.objectFocus {
    border: 1px solid red;
    outline: none!important;
}
```

Comment: I need to highlight the object that the mouse is over.I can not do only for input.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'need to highlight the object'.. maybe you need to have all those 'objects' have some class like 'tobefocused' and then $('.tobefocused').on('focus', function () {
    $(this).addClass('objectFocus');
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
$('.tobefocused').on('blur', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('objectFocus');
});